How to Uninstall Add-on Feature
I have used Tridion Sites UI to install ADD-ON feature by providing dummy URL http://tridionx-qa-xx:83/addon/ui, After installing CMS and Publisher is full of Add-on logs.
How Can I remove Add-on Feature only, Thank you in advance.

If I understand correctly, you have initially misconfigured your Add-ons Service URL and are getting runtime errors from that. Now you want to remove the Add-ons Service altogether? Why is that? Why not fix the configuration?  Add-ons Service has become quite an important subsystem in Tridion Sites.

Currently management asked not to install new features that is the reason I want to uninstall

You can disable the add-on instead of uninstalling the add-on , will that work for you.

Sure that works Anand, How Can I do that?

Hi @AnandNS can you please suggest how to disable Addon feature in Tridion CMS

I think what Anand meant is that you can disable individual Add-ons in the Add-ons Service, not disable the entire Add-ons service itself. Although it's technically possible to do so, I'm not sure if it's officially supported. Note that the Add-ons feature is listed as "core feature": https://docs.rws.com/1099765/393556/tridion-sites-10-main-documentation/installing-core-features

Thank you Rick, I dont have any addons installed, When I try to rerun the installer and I am unable to see Feature to be selected to Uninstall.

I have reinstalled CMS server and skipped Add-on Service, Now those errors are gone.
